# A humble little symbol riddle

Tags: word, cipher, wordplay, rebus, english

```
{um} - [] ⼔erized
```

The answer is a common phrase. (Though note that this doesn't mean it's a famous phrase or that it often stands on its own.)

If this is too hard I will add some hints!

If your browser shows a question mark in a box:

> That's the unicode character U+2F14.

Comment: What is the character after `[]` - a question mark inside of a box?

Comment: Ah, it is not, let me add a clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I'm thinking the answer might be

> COMING EARLY, as in "winter's coming early this year!"

Explanation:

> We are presented with {um} - [], which can be described as "UM IN CURLY BRACKETS (minus) BRACKETS", or "UM IN CURLY". The unicode character is the radical spoon, which makes the next direction "Spoonerized", essentially switching the first consonant sounds of our words. Therefore, "UM IN CURLY" becomes either "COMING EARLY" or "COME IN EARLY", and I've only ever heard one of those phrases...

Comment: Very nice! I actually had the second phrase in mind. (I'd be very surprised if you really haven't heard it before, maybe you're just not thinking of it in context?)

Comment: @Luke perhaps the context is simply eluding me right now!

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/63012108.jpg

Comment: I call them "braces" so I never would have gotten that one. Good job!